# Gather data about existing tree-like data

Tags: haskell, tree, traversal

Let's say we have existing tree-like data and we would like to add information about depth of each node. How can we easily achieve that?

```
Data Tree = Node Tree Tree | Leaf
```

For each node we would like to know in constant complexity how deep it is. We have the data from external module, so we have information as it is shown above. Real-life example would be external HTML parser which just provides the XML tree and we would like to gather data e.g. how many hyperlinks every node contains.

Functional languages are created for traversing trees and gathering data, there should be an easy solution.

Obvious solution would be creating parallel structure. Can we do better?

Comment: ... that's not the point of functional languages. Also, the data structure you have defined isn't terribly useful since it only keeps track of the shape of the tree, not the data in it.

Comment: Well you can imagine that there is also big data contained within, that's just simplification.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. There's a sizable body of knowledge regarding tree annotations in Haskell, which an answer could meaningfully cover.

Answer (score 4):

The standard trick, which I learned from Chris Okasaki's wonderful [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) is to cache the results of expensive operations at each node. (Perhaps this trick was known before Okasaki's thesis; I don't know.) You can provide smart constructors to manage this information for you so that constructing the tree need not be painful. For example, when the expensive operation is depth, you might write:

```
module SizedTree (SizedTree, sizedTree, node, leaf, depth) where

data SizedTree = Node !Int SizedTree SizedTree | Leaf

node l r = Node (max (depth l) (depth r) + 1) l r
leaf = Leaf

depth (Node d _ _) = d
depth Leaf = 0

-- since we don't expose the constructors, we should
-- provide a replacement for pattern matching
sizedTree f v (Node _ l r) = f l r
sizedTree f v Leaf = v
```

Constructing `SizedTree`s costs O(1) extra work at each node (hence it is O(n) work to convert an n-node `Tree` to a `SizedTree`), but the payoff is that checking the depth of a `SizedTree` -- or of any subtree -- is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Nice solution. Do you want `Node !Int ...`?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs That's probably a good idea. Consider it stolen!

Comment: You can't steal something that is freely given. :)

Comment: Unless I don't understand something, I don't see how this is relevant for the answer. It doesn't really provide a way to extract/morph data from existing structure.

Comment: @JKS It is easy to convert from your existing structure to this structure. `convert :: Tree -> SizedTree; convert Leaf = leaf; convert (Node l r) = node l r`.

Comment: Well, the problem is that parallel structures aren't quite maintainable. If source changes, then all source code needs refactoring. Also, I can't use functions already written for traversals of old structure. What I'm looking for is just making attachment to existing thing. I'm not sure if this is asking for impossible, but it's like I need mapping all nodes to new attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You do need some another data where you can store these `Int`s. Define `Tree` as

```
data Tree a = Node Tree a Tree | Leaf a
```

and then write a function

```
annDepth :: Tree a -> Tree (Int, a)
```

Your original `Tree` is `Tree ()` and with pattern synonyms you can recover nice constructors.

---

If you want to preserve the original tree for some reason, you can define a view:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds #-}

data Shape = SNode Shape Shape | SLeaf

data Tree a sh where
    Leaf :: a -> Tree a SLeaf
    Node :: Tree a lsh -> a -> Tree a rsh -> Tree a (SNode lsh rsh)
```

With this you have a guarantee that an annotated tree has the same shape as the unannotated. But this doesn't work good without proper dependent types.

---

Also, have a look at the question [Boilerplate-free annotation of ASTs in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157717/boilerplate-free-annotation-of-asts-in-haskell)

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is what @DanielWagner suggested, just extend the data structure. This can be somewhat inconvenient, but can be solved: Smart constructors for creating instances and using [records for pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9066087/1333025).

Perhaps [Data types a la carte](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.4131&rep=rep1&type=pdf) could help, although I haven't used this approach myself. There is a library [compdata](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata) based on that.

A completely different approach would be to efficiently memoize the values you need. I was trying to solve a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13098448/1333025) and one of the solutions is provided by the library [stable-memo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stable-memo). Note that this isn't a purely functional approach, as the library is internally based on object identity, but the interface is pure and works perfectly for the purpose.